# Real time loop issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having problem archiving real time loop. While it going to next iteration, it should check the `status` first for an update (`status= 0`) before going to next iteration.

status field might be updated somewhere else...

**For example:**

```
<?php
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE status = 0";
$query = $db->prepare($SQL);
$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
    print("\n\n");
    sleep(5);
}
?>
```

While php script is running/looping, in mysql console, I quickly did:

```
UPDATE data SET status = 1
```

It is still showing all the records even I have updated the status. How can that problem be fixed?

Comment: Not possible...! Consider running multiple queries with `LIMIT OFFSET, COUNT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result set is only computed once.  If you want to see intermediate updates, you need to issue another SELECT statement.

Comment: another SELECT statement in the while loop?

Comment: If you're going to wait a bit and then look for changed records, you need to do the entire query/fetch cycle again.

Comment: When I add $query->execute();  in the fetch loop, it work fine

Comment: That makes sense. `$query->execute();` is redoing your query from the start.  You'll never get more than one row at a time this way, though.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the while loop you've long gone fron the DB, you're simply displaying now what was sent back.

Comment: Yes I understand, my question was how can it be solved to see intermediate updates.

Comment: like suggested, get the super-set (id's of items you want to display), then loop those and re-query each again... not the nicest way. This could still mean someone may update after you've displayed. You could also do it the way you are, but use jquery and refresh it regularly as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You must requery the database each time you want to get freash data. Otherwise, you will only re-iterate over the old fetched data.

```
<?php
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE status = 0";

while (true) { // set the condition you need here (eg: time)

    // I don't know PDO enough to know if prepare can be executed out of the loop
    $query = $db->prepare($SQL);

    // re-query the database to get the new statuses
    $query->execute();

    // process the data
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($row);
        print("\n\n");
    }

    // sleep when all the row have been processed
    sleep(5);
}
?>
```

Comment: That actually wont work for my requirement. That going to loop the fetch loop again and again.  Im going to run multiple script at the same time. I've put $query->execute(); in the fetch loop and it seem to work.